# $\rm Cu_2O_3$ and cuprate HTS

Tags: superconductivity

According to English Wikipedia [Cu2O3](https://www.osti.gov/dataexplorer/biblio/dataset/1291638) “[is a hypothetical inorganic compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(III)_oxide)”, which “has not been isolated as a pure solid”.
Curiously, Russian Wikipedia tells a [somewhat different story](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8(III)), stating that $\rm Cu_2O_3$ forms red crystals, which are stable up to 75°С. A relevant reference is [this one](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.53.8028), whose scan is freely available on the web.
What motivates my question is the fact that Cu+++ oxides are constituents of cuprate superconductors and that  the electron holes in Cu++ (turning it into Cu+++) are thought (by Anderson at least) to be the superconducting carriers. $\rm Cu_2O_3$ is the most stripped down version of a cuprate I can think of. My admittedly naive question is the following: is there any obvious reason why it should not superconduct?